# I want to train myself to use the Chinese grammar particle 了 correctly: how do I go about doing that?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese

*Motivation*: In Chinese grammar, there's a particle 了 which has two main uses: [completion 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22) (post-verb) and [change-of-state 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Change_of_state_with_%22le%22) (end of sentence).  I'm bad at using this particle (see [How does someone train using 了 correctly?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/how-does-someone-train-using-%e4%ba%86-correctly) at Chinese.SE) and I want to find a way to *train* myself to use this particle correctly.

**Question**: I want to train myself to use the Chinese grammar particle 了 correctly: how do I go about doing that?

To illustrate what I have in mind: when I want to learn something in chess, I do it again and again (training, drills, repetition, familiarization, etc.) until it's hard for me to get it wrong.  I'm after some kind of training program for learning the Chinese 了.

---

I asked basically the same question on Chinese.SE (the aforementioned [How does someone train using 了 correctly?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/how-does-someone-train-using-%e4%ba%86-correctly)), however, I feel it might be more on topic here: it's about the learning process, and how to do so efficiently.  The question could probably apply to other languages (I'd guess both Japanese and Korean).  It's very possible learners of other languages have applicable skills.

Comment: When I was still learning Chinese, one of my teachers told me the following story: she and a few colleagues had gone to China for additional teacher training. When their teacher (a native speaker, obviously), asked what topic they would like to discuss, my teacher proposed the usage of 了. The Chinese teacher asked whether they could choose a different topic ... (The moral of the story is that even native speakers can't really capture all usages of 了 in neat rules.)